# Access request data at login page

Tags: java, security, jsp, servlets

The link below is a secure URL, and I need to persist the "resource" parameter after the login because it is used to redirect the user after a successful login.

```
http://wwwtest.mycompany.com/mwa/ssologin?resource=/content/en/home.html
```

web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured</web-resource-name>
        <description></description>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/jsp/apps/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/ssologin</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <description>protectedlinks</description>
        <role-name>protected</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>mycompany.com</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>
    Protected portion of site</description>
    <role-name>protected</role-name>
</security-role>
```

login.jsp - user appears to be redirected to login.jsp and the request attributes (including the "resource" URL param) no longer exist

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="login?resource=<c:out value='${param.resource}'/>">
Username: 
<br/>
<input type="text" size="15" name="user">
<br/>
Password: 
<br/>
<input type="password" size="15" name="password">
<br/>
<input type="Submit" value="Login">
```

When I try to access the request via a TagLib or a Filter it appears that the Web Container (WebSphere) is performing a redirect my login.jsp.  The ${param.resource} does not work either due to the redirect.

The easiest solution would be to have the browser perform a forward instead of a redirect, but so far I cannot find a way to enforce a forward in the security constraints (or anywhere else).  I have thought of a few other convoluted session flows, but I like none of them.

The only solution that is somewhat acceptable is to include some JavaScript that updates the action to include the URL params, but that does not work all the time because some browsers leave the original URL and some are updated to the redirect URL (wwwtest.mycompany.com/mwa/login.jsp).

How can I either enforce request to be forwarded instead of redirected for security, or get around this problem in a different manner altogether?

**UPDATE**

- The resource param is dynamic and set by a 3rd party
- My JSTL/EL syntax works absolutely fine if I remove the url-pattern "/ssologin"
- hidden parameter will not work because the "resource" param is no longer on the request

Thanks, 
     Sean

Comment: is resource dynamic? If not, simply hardcode it

Comment: I should have been more explicit, the "resource" parameter is dynamic and provided by some 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

Take a hidden field in your form (login) and

```
<input type="hidden" name="someParam" value="${param.resource}"/>
```

You will receive this on next form POST (upon submission of loginForm)

Also as mentioned by BalusC you need to escape the XML by

```
<input type="hidden" name="resource" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.resource)}"/>
```

Comment: The field name is missing and there's a XSS hole.

Comment: @BalusC could you please elaborate more on how XSS here?

Comment: The `${param.resource}` needs to be HTML-escaped, otherwise the enduser can supply malicious JavaScript code and have it executed. Use `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()` to escape it. `<input type="hidden" name="resource" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.resource)}"/>`

Comment: The EL/JSTL I am using works fine if I make this page non-secure, so it is not an issue with the syntax of my output.  During the troubleshooting process, I created a test TagLib, which I then debugged and the request does not have any of the attributes on it.  My guess is because the browser is performing a redirect.

Comment: Did you set the parameter in hidden field and then do you POST it ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I have no control over the flow because a 3rd party app uses my login flow for authentication (the URL above).  As far as we can tell, the 3rd party app can only insert params in the URL, but even if they could use hidden fields, it would not matter because it appears that a redirect occurs, which wipes out the request data.

Comment: if you have control of login form you could do it with mentioned instructions

Comment: The Login form (login.jsp) is where the user is redirected to.  Prior to arriving there a redirect occurs, which wipes out the request attributes.

Comment: FYI for those in the future: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbq it appears that the spec requires the App Server to perform a REDIRECT to the declared <login-config> (typically login.jsp).  Therefore, passing params to the login.jsp directly does not appear to be an option.  I need to rethink how I will accomplish this.